# Getting an XML sent by Webservice(POST method) in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, post

I am developing this application where I need to send an XML file to a webservice and read it from the webservice, and applying the business logic from the webservice, it will send an XML as response.

The thing is that I do know how to read the response the webservice sends, but I don't know how to retrieve the XML that the request sends to the webservice, the variable always comes null. If someone could help me out, I'd be really glad.

Request Method:

```
(...)
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var XMLRequest = Util.BuildXML.CreateRequestXML();

            string url = string.Format(WEB_API_HOST + "/Application/MyMethod/");

            HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                Content = new StringContent(XMLRequest.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
            };

            var task = client.SendAsync(httpRequest).ContinueWith((taskwithmsg) =>
            {
                var response = taskwithmsg.Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var xmlResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(xmlResponse);

                    var test = doc.SelectSingleNode("RESPONSE/...").InnerText;

                }
                else
                {
                    var contentTask = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    throw new Exception(contentTask);
                }
            });

            task.Wait();
        }
    (...)
```

And the Webservice ( that is supposed to receive the XML and read it)

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod(XmlDocument doc)
    {

        // Any doc.SelectSingleNode() wouldn't work, the doc variable is null.

        var response = new StringBuilder();

        response.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
        response.Append("<RESPONSE>");
        (...)
        response.Append("</RESPONSE>");

        var xmlResponse = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(response.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
        };

        return xmlResponse;
    }
```

So how do I get to read the xml in the "MyMethod" method?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Are you asking how to parse XML, or why it's coming in as null? I'm not sure what you're asking here. Is the request getting received server-side?

Comment: well, I thought that setting the Content in the httpRequest scope would send the XML to the webservice, but it comes as null(perhaps because I put it as a parameter and I should try to get it using a different approach). The problem is that it comes as null, I'm not receiving any data(I might, but I don't know how to get it if so).

Comment: Is this built on Web API? Or some other framework?

Comment: I created a fake WebService. It's pretty much two projects running on the same solution.

Comment: That doesn't *really* answer my question, but fair enough. Are you sure that whatever framework you're using has a mapping to accept `XmlDocument`s from requests, parse them, and put them into parameters? In most if not all I've seen, you'd need to specify *at least* that this particular parameter was meant to come from the request body.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.5, MVC 4 and NHibernate. I'm not well experienced, that is the main problem.. well, even if it doesn't actually parse the data, is there a way to retrieve it from the webservice? I mean, there must be some sort of client.GendAsync() or something.

Comment: When I receive data from the other project(the fake webservice) on the line [var xmlResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;], it works fine. I just wanted to do something exactly like this, but on the second method(HttpResponseMessage MyMethod)